# fetching the document id

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I fetch the document id of an open document in Word? I need that doc id to upload the opened document to a server. Can I do this by creating an instance of that document and use some property?

Answer (score 1):

You can also hash the document and use the hash as ID, using a good hashing algorithm like SHA512 will guarantee a unique ID for every document.

Answer (score 1):

you need `ActiveDocument` from the `Word.Application`

something like (c# is a long time ago for me)

```
var word = Word.Application;
var doc = word.ActiveDocument;
```

provided you have office library's loaded

Answer (score 0):

you can use file/path combination as an id, because it will be uniqe for each file on the computer.